# Redux Toolkit is not working with my Next.js App: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get my **Next.JS** app working with Redux Toolkit. For context, I want to use Redux Toolkit for my application to implement the cart functionality. The number of products in cart should be managed by a global state hence I am using the Redux Toolkit.

[image: In the image, the Redux Devtools extension shows that the cart state is 2 which is correct. But I am getting the error that is shown on the left side.]

Here is what my code looks like:

**store.js**

```
   import {configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import cartReducer from './slices/cart'

    export default configureStore({
     reducer: {
        cart: cartReducer
     }
})
```

**cart.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  cart: 2,
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.cart += 1
    },

    decrement: (state) => {
      state.cart -= 1
    },

    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.cart += action.payload
    },
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

**_app.js**

```
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import {useState} from 'react';
import {store } from '../store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return(

    <Provider store={store}>
    
        <Layout>

            <Component {...pageProps} />


        </Layout>

    </Provider>
  )
 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the _app.js file:

```
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
import '@/styles/globals.css'

import {useState} from 'react';
import { store }  from '../store.js';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return(

    <Provider store={store}>
    
        <Layout>

            <Component {...pageProps} />


        </Layout>

    </Provider>
  )


}
```

I removed the currely braces from the line:

```
import { store }  from '../store.js';
```

i.e.

`import store   from '../store.js';`

This solved my issue.